# Cannot import name IMDb from imdb

Tags: python-3.x, imdb

import imdb

from imdb import IMDb

ia = imdb.IMDb()

search = ia.get_top20_movies()

for i in range(1,10):

```
print(search[i])
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'IMDb' from 'imdb'

Comment: You can format code in a code box when you add 4 spaces in front of every line.  The last line in the for-loop gets 8 spaces, then.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the `imdb` module. You can easily install it using `pip`.

Assuming that you are using Python3, simply run the command below in your terminal if you are using macOS or Linux, or run it in the command prompt if you are using Windows.

```
python3 -m pip install --user imdbpy
```

Comment: You don't need to use the --user flag in most cases. I can do without it all the time.

Comment: Unless you have an admin password.